# why docker daemon command not present on 18-ce version?

Tags: docker

i have docker server and docker client version 18.03.1-ce on my machine. but 
when execute

`sudo docker daemon`

I get

> docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command

With `-d` command get same result:

> unknown shorthand flag

is this command available on docker EE or something goes wrong on my machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `dockerd` and not `docker daemon`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#repositoryshortid-image-references

> docker daemon subcommand
>   Deprecated In Release: v1.13.0